# Class not inheriting from object?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, typeinfo

I am working on a method that is using reflection to inspect parameter types of methods. This methods iterates through the ParameterInfo's and is doing something with the types of those parameters.

I was always under the assumption that if `TypeInfo.IsClass` is `true`, that this type is a class and always derives (indirectly) from type `object` (except when the type is `object` itself of course). So, if `TypeInfo.IsClass` is true, `TypeInfo.BaseType` must be set.

Well my assumption was wrong! There are classes that do NOT derive from type `object`. And my assumption messed up my code.

For example:

```
Type type = typeof(int).MakeByRefType();
```

`type.IsClass` will be `true` and `type.BaseType` will be `null`.

If you think about it, it is logical. And I can prevent my code to crash by checking `TypeInfo.IsByRef`.

**Now my question is: are there more such 'exotic' types (besided the ByRef-types and type `object`) which are a class (`IsClass == true`) but do not have a base type  (`BaseType == null`)?**

Before you answer: I am only refering to types where `IsClass == true`! And my example with type `int` was just an example. It could have been any type. 
So please no:

- Interfaces
- Structs
- Void

**Answers so far:**

- ByRef types  (`T&`): as descrybed in the question.
- Pointer types (`T*`): Found by Mark Gravell.

Comment: All reference-to-[value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) for sure. Also the "`void` reference" type.

Comment: just a guess, but have you checked the dynamic - type?

Comment: @user287107: `dynamic` is the same as `object` as far as the type system is concerned.

Comment: @Jon: All value types derive indirectly from `object`. A value type derives from `ValueType` and `ValueType` derives from `object`.

Comment: @MartinMulder: I edited the comment to be more precise; I meant "reference-to-value-type types", as in your example.

Comment: @Jon: `typoef(void).IsClass` ==> `false`.

Comment: @MartinMulder: `typeof(void).MakeByRefType().IsClass` ==> `true`.

Comment: @Jon can you link to the documentation that states that any `ValueType&` types don't inherit from `object` (or otherwise display this behavior)?

Comment: @MartinMulder: Regarding the edit -- I hope you realize that `int` is also a struct and the only thing that makes `IsClass` `true` is the `MakeByRefType()`.

Comment: @dialer: No, I everything I have here is from observation only. Did not find anything relevant with a quick search on MSDN.

Comment: @Jon: About the VOid.MakeByRefType... that is the same thing I already have in my question. **ANY** ByRefType is a class. (Very curious in what world a refernce to void would be handy, but that is another matter.)

Comment: Interesting question, doesn't deserve downvotes, IMO

Comment: @MartinMulder: I think you should remove the list at the end of the question -- it's not really useful -- and replace it with "I am interested in anything that is not the result of calling MakeByRefType()`.

Comment: Downvoters, please comment why.

Comment: @Jon: Well... my list should not be there, but I already got two answers: One refered to interfaces (of which IsClass == false), and one was about `object`, which I already covedred in my question.

Comment: @MartinMulder The one which you say that is "about interfaces" quotes MSDN saying "Object is the only type that does not have a base type, therefore null is returned as the base type of Object.", which, as I pointed out in a comment, is a precise answer to your question. What else do you want?

Comment: @DanielDaranas It seems like *any* `TypeName&` type (that you get from `typeof(TypeName).MakeByRefType()` has `IsClass == true` and `BaseType == null`. That is interesting, but I can't find anything in the documentation about this (we might have to try summoning Jon Skeet). However, it does also have `IsByRef == true`, so you could check for that as well.

Comment: Downvoters, please comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say that `IsClass` is simply misleading here. It states:

> Gets a value indicating whether the System.Type is a class; that is, not a value type or interface.

and it is *implemented* this way: it checks whether the flags include `Interface`, and whether it is a `ValueType`.

Unfortunately, there are more things that this. Pointers *are not managed types*. A by-ref is very similar to a pointer. Pointer are not `object`s, although in common use the cast is actually a de-reference/cast. The same applies for things like direct pointers such as `int*`.

Not everything in .NET is an `object` :)

```
var baseType = typeof(int*).BaseType; // null
bool liesAndMoreLies = typeof(int*).IsClass; // true
```

[Eric Lippert covers this more here: Not everything derives from object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/not-everything-derives-from-object) - and lists a few other examples (open generic types, for example).

Comment: @MartinMulder for a while there I thought that it reported `IsClass` as `false`, but actually it reports `true` - so indeed, it is pretty-much the same as the exotic type in the question

Answer (score 2):

Except generic types which are not instantiated, is pointed out with the link [Not everything derives from object @ Mr. Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) by [Mr. Gravell's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461524/class-not-inheriting-from-object/16462002#16462002), I suggest that to find the other types met your requirement can be done by yourself.

Now, let's start from scratch to solve this question. First off, the types your are going to figure out, should be in the core runtime library, and which is `mscorlib.dll`:

```
public static partial class MartinMulderExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetMscorlibTypes() {
        return
            from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            let name=assembly.ManifestModule.Name
            where 0==String.Compare("mscorlib.dll", name, true)
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            select type;
    }
}
```

And then, the types have the `MakeXXXXType()` methods such as `MakeByRefType()`. Here we take more possibility into account, that is **any method** which returns **a type or types**. Since we have zero knowledge about the arguments for an **arbitrary type**, we consider **methods take zero argument**:

```
partial class MartinMulderExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetRetrievableTypes(this Type type) {
        var typesArray=(
            from method in type.GetMethods()
            where 0==method.GetParameters().Count()

            let typeArray=
                method.InvokeZeroArgumentMethodWhichReturnsTypeOrTypes(type)

            where null!=typeArray
            select typeArray).ToArray();

        var types=
            typesArray.Length>0
                ?typesArray.Aggregate(Enumerable.Union)
                :Type.EmptyTypes;

        return types.Union(new[] { type });
    }
}
```

For the implementation of `InvokeZeroArgumentMethodWhichReturnsTypeOrTypes`, however, there are several invalid cases of this kind of invocation, such as invoking `GetGenericParameterConstraints()` on a non-generic type; we are avoiding these cases with *try-catch*:

```
partial class MartinMulderExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Type>
        InvokeZeroArgumentMethodWhichReturnsTypeOrTypes(
        this MethodInfo method, Type t
        ) {
        try {
            if(typeof(Type)==method.ReturnType) {
                var type=method.Invoke(t, null) as Type;

                if(null!=type)
                    return new[] { type };
            }

            if(typeof(Type[])==method.ReturnType) {
                var types=method.Invoke(t, null) as Type[];

                if(types.Length>0)
                    return types;
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException) {
        }
        catch(TargetInvocationException) {
        }
        catch(TargetException) {
        }

        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }
}
```

And now, to figure out the desired types. Let's construct the method step by step. The first step would be define the scope of all possible types:

```
partial class MartinMulderExtensions {
    public static Type[] GetDesiredTypes() {
        return (
            from type in MartinMulderExtensions.GetMscorlibTypes()
            .Select(x => x.GetRetrievableTypes())
            .Aggregate(Enumerable.Union)
```

Then, according to what you stated basically:

> **Now my question is: are there more such 'exotic' types (besided the ByRef-types and type `object`) which are a class (`IsClass == true`) but do not have a base type  (`BaseType == null`)?**

```
            where null==type.BaseType
            where type.IsClass
```

You also stated that for `before answer`:

> Before you answer: I am only refering to types where `IsClass == true`! And my example with type `int` was just an example. It could have been any type. 
>   So please no:
>
> - Interfaces
> - Structs
> - Void

```
            where !type.IsInterface
            where !type.IsValueType
            where typeof(void)!=type
```

The final step, let's skip which are already answered and complete the method:

```
            where !type.IsByRef
            where !type.IsPointer
            select type
            ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

So now, you can invoke `MartinMulderExtensions.GetDesiredTypes()` to get the types you desired:

```
public partial class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        foreach(var type in MartinMulderExtensions.GetDesiredTypes())
            Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
}
```

---

For the complete code:

```
public static partial class MartinMulderExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetMscorlibTypes() {
        return
            from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            let name=assembly.ManifestModule.Name
            where 0==String.Compare("mscorlib.dll", name, true)
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            select type;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type>
        InvokeZeroArgumentMethodWhichReturnsTypeOrTypes(
        this MethodInfo method, Type t
        ) {
        try {
            if(typeof(Type)==method.ReturnType) {
                var type=method.Invoke(t, null) as Type;

                if(null!=type)
                    return new[] { type };
            }

            if(typeof(Type[])==method.ReturnType) {
                var types=method.Invoke(t, null) as Type[];

                if(types.Length>0)
                    return types;
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException) {
        }
        catch(TargetInvocationException) {
        }
        catch(TargetException) {
        }

        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetRetrievableTypes(this Type type) {
        var typesArray=(
            from method in type.GetMethods()
            where 0==method.GetParameters().Count()

            let typeArray=
                method.InvokeZeroArgumentMethodWhichReturnsTypeOrTypes(type)

            where null!=typeArray
            select typeArray).ToArray();

        var types=
            typesArray.Length>0
                ?typesArray.Aggregate(Enumerable.Union)
                :Type.EmptyTypes;

        return types.Union(new[] { type });
    }

    public static Type[] GetDesiredTypes() {
        return (
            from type in MartinMulderExtensions.GetMscorlibTypes()
            .Select(x => x.GetRetrievableTypes())
            .Aggregate(Enumerable.Union)

            where null==type.BaseType
            where type.IsClass
            where !type.IsInterface
            where !type.IsValueType
            where typeof(void)!=type

            where !type.IsByRef
            where !type.IsPointer

            select type
            ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Type.GetElementType Method [(from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx)

The Type of the object encompassed or referred to by the current array, pointer, or reference type, or null if the current Type is not an array or a pointer, or is not passed by reference, or represents a generic type or a type parameter in the definition of a generic type or generic method.

Code...

```
Type type = typeof(int).MakeByRefType();
bool isClass = type.IsClass; // true

Type elementType = type.GetElementType(); // Int32
Type baseType = elementType.BaseType; // ValueType
```

Comment: How is this an answer to my question? I am looking for more exotic types. Not a way to change an exotic type to a normal type.

Comment: You said there are classes that do not derive from Object. It seems to me you were boxing an integer and investigating the base type the wrong way. There is a base type.

Comment: Your exotic types do not exist. Object is the only type that does not have a base type. Why don't you reply to my last comment and then explain your downvote.

Comment: They do not exists? So you claim my example code will produce a runtime exception?

Comment: Investigate the wrong way? I simply state that the exotic type `int&` is marked as a class but does not have a base type. I am simply asking if there are more of these exotic types. I am NOT asking for how to analyze them.

Comment: Define exotic?  You say they are "exotic" because IsClass == true while the base type is null. Wrong! The base type is not null. When you are boxing an integer the base type is evaluated differently, as I posted above.

Comment: Did you even test it? You say `TypeInfo.BaseType` is not null... just test it. Create a program which will write `IsClass` and `BaseType` to the console and see if they are `true` + `null` or not.

Comment: I would wager that the guys that built the .net framework have some insights into this. If I call GetElementType() and then check the basetype it will not be null. What do you suppose GetElementType() is for?

Comment: I did test it... and I pasted the code above and IsClass==true and after calling GetElementType() and checking the BaseType... it is not null but instead shows the exact base type I would expect.

Comment: `GetElementType()` has nothing to do with it. `GetElementType()`  is used to get the element type of an array. Or a reference type. So in this case `GetElementType` and `MakeByRefType` are each others compliment functions. They both return a type. Of of those types does NOT have a basetype.

Comment: My question is: Are there more 'exotic' types (and I define in my question what I mean by it). Where is your question? Where is the exitoc type you have found?

Comment: MakeByRefType will make a reference type from a type. GetElementType gets the type of the object referred to by the reference type.

Comment: I do understand your question but your definition of exotic types makes no sense because you are using MakeByRefType to create a type and refusing to use GetElementType to get the type from which you can determine its base type.

Comment: Then you do not get my question.

Comment: QUESTION: Now my question is: are there more such 'exotic' types (besided the ByRef-types and type object) which are a class (IsClass == true) but do not have a base type (BaseType == null)?  ANSWER: the ByRef-types and type object do have base types, your question implies they do not but the fact is you are not using GetElementType which is the proper way to determine the base type of ByRef-types.

Comment: I created a list of correct answers. Make sure you find another answer so I can put you in the list. Any other comments or answers about how to find a base type another way are not correct answers!

Comment: Why don't you at least try GetElementType()... see if you get the base type you would expect.  GetElementType() is also needed when dealing with pointers when you want to get the base type.

Comment: I know how `GetElementType()` works. I already knew BEFORE I asked the question. So I am not looking for an explaination of it.

Comment: @user2315985 When you write a method that just accepts a `Type`, then you _can't make any other assumptions about that `Type`_. For example, you can't do `GetElementType` because _you don't know_ if there is an element type. So using only `IsClass` and `BaseType`, can you find more instances of `Type` for which `IsClass` is true and `BaseType` is null?

Comment: You said it in your own post... "There are classes that do NOT derive from type object." Yet if you use GetElementType() and check the base type it is not null and returns the proper base class as expected. If you understand GetElementType() why in the world would you not use it?  Instead you think that some exotic classes exist that do not have a base type? Fact: Besides Object, all types have a base type. Object does not. If you are checking a Reference Type after using MakeByRefType, the proper way to check the base class of the object referred to by the base class is to use GetElementType

Comment: @user: I am aware of the function `GetElementType` and what it does. I knew this BEFORE I posted this question. I am aways that, using this function, I can get the base type of the element of the reference type. But I am not interested in finding base types of elements. I am only interested in `exotic` types as defined in my question. If you post an answer with a new exotic type, I will put your answer there too.

Comment: Well you only have two things listed, reference types and pointers, neither of which are exotic and both of which refer objects that have a base type. They are not mysterious or strange... they are well documented on MSDN so you might want to rename them from exotic to something else.